# Winforms chart causing unit tests to stall

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I have a number of unit tests that I have noticed some unusual behaviour with, specifically that an async call seems to hang after another test creates a winforms Chart. Digging into it deeper, I can replicate it by a very simple setup. 
The code to replicate the issue is as follows.

```
private async Task ADelay()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}

private void PlayWithChart()
{
    var chart = new Chart();

    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    chart.SaveImage(stream, ChartImageFormat.Jpeg);
    stream.Position = 0;

    chart.Dispose();
    stream.Dispose();
}

[Test]
public async Task Chart_example1()
{
    PlayWithChart();

    var astring = await ADelay().ContinueWith(e => "123");

    Assert.That(astring, Is.EqualTo("123"));
}
```

If you run the above test it will hang on the "await" call, second line in the test.

However if you comment out the "var chart = new Chart();" and the other lines referencing the chart, then the test passes fine.

So I'm assuming something to do with the way the Chart control (from winforms) is constructed, does something with the threading context to cause this issue.

Has anyone encountered this or knows how to fix it? Is it a matter of creating the Chart on a separate STA thread or something like that?

Comment: Does doing the same memorystream saving with some other object, say a Bitmap work?

Comment: It actually even causes the same behaviour if you comment out the SaveImage() line completely and just create the new Chart() object and dispose it without touching it

Comment: I can't reproduce on win10pro/64bit.